# SCSS – How to get specific value from a nested map

Tags: css, sass, frontend, buefy

I'm trying to customize something in Buefy/Bulma and I need to get some value from SCSS map. I have following:

```
$colors:
   (
    "white": (
      $white,
      $black
    ),
    ...
  );
```

For my needs I want to get the first position (only $white) from

```
 @each $color in $colors {
  .button.is-#{nth($color, 1)}.pulse {
    position: relative;
    &::after {
      position: absolute;
      content: nth($color, 2); //This returns both colors
   ...
```

Now I am getting both ($white, $black).
Please, help – is there a way to get only the result of the "$white" variable from this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can not store a variable in a map without a value. E.g. `white: #fff,` instead of `$white`

Comment: Value is defined i my file, but not in this stack. I have it defined as white color (#fff)

Comment: Actually – this returns value in this format: "#fff, #000" – I need only the first one

Comment: If  have another question before I can provide you the solution, why is there a map nested within the map, when it could be `$colors: (white: ..., black: ...);`?

Comment: This is OOTB by Bulma and it cannot be changed. Under e.g. white there is the exact color and its inverted variant (black)

Answer (score 0):

### [Codepen](https://codepen.io/SimplyCius/pen/NWNzKmN)

In this case then:

```
$white: #fff;
$black: #000;

$colors: (
  white: (
    $white,
    $black,
  ),
);

@function returnColor($value) {
  @return nth(map-get($colors, white), index(map-get($colors, white), $value));
}

body {
  color: returnColor($white);
}
```

If there are multiple nested maps, then:

```
$white: #fff;
$black: #000;

$red: red;
$invert: toLazy;

$colors: (
  white: (
    $white,
    $black,
  ),
  red: (
    $red,
    $invert,
  ),
);

@function returnColor($map, $value) {
  @return nth(map-get($colors, $map), index(map-get($colors, $map), $value));
}

body {
  background-color: returnColor(red, $invert);
  color: returnColor(white, $white);
}
```

```
body {
  background-color: toLazy;
  color: #fff;
}
```